# How can I block comment code in an IPython notebook with a German keyboard?

Tags: comments, jupyter-notebook

How can I block comment a selected text in an IPython Notebook with a German keyboard layout? Ctrl-/ does not work, which on a German keyboard actually is Ctrl-Shift-7.

Answer (score 13):

I found this great workaround for international keyboard layouts from Dataman in [How do I comment out multiple lines in Jupyter Ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502057/6730499)

> Press the `Alt` button and keep holding it. The cursor should change
>   its shape into a big plus sign. The next step is, using your mouse, to
>   point to the beginning of the first line you want to comment and while
>   holding the `Alt` button pull down your mouse until the last line you
>   want to comment. Finally, you can release the `Alt` button and then
>   use the `#` character to comment.

Comment: That's really a great workaround and useful in many other places as well.

Comment: this doesn't work in Jupyter Lab... it replaces all lines with the #.

Comment: FYI @Edgar : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3753 and https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-shortcutui/issues/34

Comment: Works fine for me with Jupiter-lab on Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used it with nbextensions.
Install it. See [docs here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Then, in your [nbconfig](http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/?nbextension=comment-uncomment/main).

[image]

Just configure it with your personal preference. I am using german keyboard and used this implementation successfully for months.

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution for Jupyterlab?

Comment: I didn't find a Jupyterlab solution so far. And this is one of the reasons I still use Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @Createdd I searched for months for a decent solution for this problem. I bought a new keyboard without numpad and in jupyterlab ONLY "Ctrl" together with the division sign on the numpad worked for comment/uncomment (German layout). I still don't figured out how to change the bindings BUT I just found out that it also depends on the browser which is used. Mozilla is my default browser, when I started jupyterlab in chrome, suddenly "Ctrl+#" works too (the other binding on the numpad still works). Just wanted to let you know. I just use lab in chrome now, which is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom keyboard shortcuts in `custom.js`. For Jupyter this file is located in `.jupyter/custom/`. On a German keyboard layout I use `Ctrl` + `,` as a shortcut to comment by adding this to `custom.js`:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ],
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp",
            function () {
                IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.extraKeys = {"Ctrl-," : "toggleComment"};
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: This did not work for me (after restarting Jupyter) using Jupyter Notebook 5 under OS X 10.11

Comment: This doesn't work for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying every combination with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, voilà, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>#</kbd> does the job.

Answer (score 0):

On a Nordic keybord (and I think this goes for German as well) simply hit Ctrl+Shift+7 (=Ctrl+/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a comment by AlexanderMelde on GitHub which helped me out that is worked for me:

Strg + /

using the **devide key from the numpad** instead of the one with the "7" works for me with German keyboard layout.

Hope it also works for you!