# Multiline comment on codeblock in Jupyter Notebook 7.0.6

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**Problem:**
Multiline comment, as it did work in Notebook v6.0, doesn't work any more in Notebook v7.0.6.
Normal working keystroke in V6 Ctrl-=, or Ctrl-/ (on numeric keyboard).

**Prerequisites:**

- MacOS Ventura (via OpenCore Patcher) on MacPro
- Keyboard layout French
- Python 3.12 (via Python.org)
- Notebook 7.0.2 (latest version of writing)
- Google Chrome (as default browser for notebooks via jupyter_notebook_config)

**Tried solutions:**

- Reinstallation of Notebook v6.0, result: multiline comment works.
  – Upgrade Notebook v6.0 to v7.0.6, result: multiline comment doesn't work. Strolling the keyboard and even switching to US International keyboard, doesn't give any working key combination.
- Installation on PC Windows 11 works perfect.

**Non-solution:**

- Stick with Notebook v6.0 isn't what I'm looking for.
- Any suggestions?

Comment: Notebook 7+ adheres much more closely to how JupyterLab shortcuts work as it is built on much of the same tech. This is very different than the old document-centric interface. That said, there's some concerns about making it easy for past users to move to Notebook 7+ and so if something is missing you can raise this as an issue. There's several posts on both the technical aspects/combinations and the rationale you can read in exchanges [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/can-the-jupyter-notebook-keyboard-shortcuts-work-with-jupyter-lab/15327/4?u=fomightez), ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/most-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-for-notebook-lab/18113?u=fomightez), [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7041), and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cannot-add-new-unmapped-key-bindings-in-keyboard-shortcut-editor/16555/10?u=fomightez). Especially see ['Keyboard shortcut parity with notebook classic'](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6596) and see if your request needs to be there or is already covered.

Comment: Any chance you tried `control` +`#` already? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504796/how-can-i-block-comment-code-in-an-ipython-notebook-with-a-german-keyboard/71480779#comment132614626_71480779) said that worked with JupyterLab and since Notebook 7+ is based on that tech, it may be worth trying. (Also [this comment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3753#issuecomment-404620549) in [the old, pre-V7 (I think?) issue post 'Customize keymaps - comment | uncomment toggle'](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3753) might clarify about the different 'layers' involved.)

Comment: Oh yes, you may also want to try different browsers. I had noted that [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/comment-out-code-block-in-jupyterlab4/19520?u=fomightez). To try without touching your system, you can use JupyterLite in a browser and see what it does; go to https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and hit the green-ish-blue text next to the beaker to launch it. It all runs in your own computer (internal to the browser via web assembly (WASM)) so it isn't using anything remote and doesn't require installing anything and thus it doesn't interfere with your local installation.

Comment: [This open issue entitled 'Fix keyboard shortcut regressions in new Notebook interface'](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7041) also may be relevant. Maybe even more so than the ones I already pointed out?